# In gremlin, how do you filter by a projection?

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop

If I have a query with a line like this:

`project('faceId','count').`

how do I filter by the projected count?

This is the whole test query I'm using:

```
g.V().hasLabel('face').
......1>   project('faceId','count').
......2>     by('faceId').
......3>     by(where(without('a')).both('is similar').
......4>        where(without('a')).
......5>        store('a').
......6>        count())
==>[faceId:face1,count:4]
==>[faceId:face9,count:1]
==>[faceId:face2,count:0]
==>[faceId:face3,count:0]
==>[faceId:face4,count:0]
==>[faceId:face5,count:0]
==>[faceId:face6,count:1]
==>[faceId:face7,count:0]
==>[faceId:face8,count:0]
```

I'm trying to filter out anything that has a count of 0.  I've tried doing a filter step like this, but 'count' is a projection and not a value, so it hasn't worked for me:

`.filter{it.count > 0}`
`where(select('count').is.gt(0))`

I've also tried adding `.as('count')` at the end of the count step above, but still no luck.

** test graph **

```
// The graph
graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
g = graph.traversal()

g.addV('face').property('faceId','face1')
g.addV('face').property('faceId','face2')
g.addV('face').property('faceId','face3')
g.addV('face').property('faceId','face4')
g.addV('face').property('faceId','face5')
g.addV('face').property('faceId','face6')
g.addV('face').property('faceId','face7')
g.addV('face').property('faceId','face8')
g.addV('face').property('faceId','face9')

g.V().has('face','faceId','face1').as('a').V().has('face','faceId','face2').as('b').addE('is similar').from('a').to('b')
g.V().has('face','faceId','face1').as('a').V().has('face','faceId','face3').as('b').addE('is similar').from('a').to('b')
g.V().has('face','faceId','face1').as('a').V().has('face','faceId','face4').as('b').addE('is similar').from('a').to('b')
g.V().has('face','faceId','face1').as('a').V().has('face','faceId','face5').as('b').addE('is similar').from('a').to('b')
g.V().has('face','faceId','face2').as('a').V().has('face','faceId','face3').as('b').addE('is similar').from('a').to('b')
g.V().has('face','faceId','face2').as('a').V().has('face','faceId','face4').as('b').addE('is similar').from('a').to('b')
g.V().has('face','faceId','face5').as('a').V().has('face','faceId','face6').as('b').addE('is similar').from('a').to('b')
g.V().has('face','faceId','face6').as('a').V().has('face','faceId','face7').as('b').addE('is similar').from('a').to('b')
g.V().has('face','faceId','face8').as('a').V().has('face','faceId','face9').as('b').addE('is similar').from('a').to('b')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you had the right idea but used `gt` as a step rather than a `P` (i.e. `Predicate`):

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('face').
......1>   project('faceId','count').
......2>     by('faceId').
......3>     by(where(without('a')).both('is similar').
......4>        where(without('a')).
......5>        store('a').
......6>        count()).
......7>   filter(select('count').is(gt(0)))
==>[faceId:face1,count:4]
==>[faceId:face9,count:1]
==>[faceId:face6,count:1]
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is what I needed.  How would I have figured that out on my own  so I know how to find answers like these next time?

Comment: Well, in this case you just mistook a step for a predicate. I'm not sure google would have easily helped with that. Perhaps looking at the step arguments might have helped. Sometimes it helps to look at the javadoc for GraphTraversal to see what arguments a particular step takes: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversal.html

Comment: Thanks!  I'll take a look and do this next time for sure!